# Any experience with a SMC JXC91?

Tags: c#, ethernet, actuator

I have a JXC91 paired with an actuator LER50-K in this case. I communicate with it via ethernet ip protocol [C# ethernet ip library](http://eeip-library.de/). The only thing I want is to get the actuator name. The manual and eds file do not mention any commands for this service what I could see and the Identity Object only gives me information about the JXC model.

I have the JXC91 connected to my PC via ethernet/usb adapter and the manufacturers program (ACTC Controller) is able to find it.
Any ideas?
Thanks